# GLES 2.0 move object by screen 2D point

Tags: android, opengl-es

In openGL ES 2.0 Android,

I need to move a object by 2D screen point (eg. touch point, x = 600, y = 300)

but, on frustumM like this,

```
Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

Matrix.translateM(.. x, y, ...) is not working because values are too large by Matrix size

How can I calculate correct value in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move an object around the frustum matrix you are probably best computing the angles at which the object is. The result should then be 2 angles plus a radius - a distance toward the object. The radius may be fixed or you will need to compute it from its previous position.

Once you have the two angles and a radius then using a sphere the coordinates should be retrieved similar to:

```
x = cos(verticalAngle)*sin(horizontalAngle)*radius
y = sin(verticalAngle)*radius 
z = cos(verticalAngle)*cos(horizontalAngle)*radius
```

To get the angles you need to check your field of view and then compute the angle by using a ratio between the point location and screen size.

The field of view is defined by your border coordinates and `near` such that `right = tan(fov.x)*near*0.5` so `fov.x = atan(right*2.0/near)`. and same for `y` using top.

So with `fov` you now know what is the angle of the whole screen in both `x` and `y` dimensions. Assuming that zero is in the center of the screen (if no other matrices are applied) then the left most part is at `-fov.x*0.5`, right at `fov.x*0.5`, bottom at `-fov.y*0.5`, top at `fov.y*0.5`.

Now you need to compute relative positions of the touch depending on the screen size like `x = touch.x/screen.width` and `y = touch.y/screen.height`. Then simply apply linear interpolation with them as `T = A + (B-A)*s`:

```
horizontalAngle = -fov.x*0.5 + (fov.x*0.5 - -fov.x*0.5)*x
verticalAngle = fov.y*0.5 + (-fov.y*0.5 - fov.y*0.5)*y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matic. but your solution is too difficult to me. I found another solution that set frustumM value to screen x, y size.

Comment: @pokoso That is another way of doing it. Yet another would be to multiply the press with the inverted frustum matrix (using coordinates in range [-1,1]). But in your case watch out how you have your "near" defined. It should be relative to width or height otherwise the results in what you see on the screen may vary a lot depending on the device you are using.